# Grunt Sass to CSS not building

Tags: javascript

At the moment I have `app/styles/main.scss` and my sass is broken down into multiple structured files and imported into `main.scss`. In my `index.html` I have the following:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I'm using grunt-contrib-sass compass from what I see in my Gruntfile.js and now I want to additionally compile a single file which is `app/styles/modules/_infowindow.scss`

I've tried the following:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/modules',
      src: ['_infowindow.scss'],
      dest: '.tmp/cdn/'
    }]
  }
},
```

Terminal outputs this:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: app/styles/modules/_infowindow.scss -> .tmp/cdn/_infowindow.css
Options: (none)
```

But when I check the directory of `.tmp` there is no directory for `cdn`.

Additional:

This is my current compass settings;

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the underscore from the filename: instead of  _infowindow.scss, use infowindow.scss

Comment: @Nora yeah I did but it returns `>> Source file "app/styles/modules/infowindow.scss" not found.`

Comment: Have you renamed the file as well? You should rename the file and use the new name without underscore in your grunt task

Comment: @Nora my file structure all begin with underscores. I've renamed the infowindow file and had to import my mixin files. Think we may have an answer!

Comment: @Nora add it as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename the file so it does not use an underscore and therefore is not a partial anymore and use the new name without underscore in the grunt task.